# Unable to prove that $\sqrt{i} + \sqrt{-i}$ is a real number.

Tags: complex-numbers

I did this :-

$$
\sqrt{i} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}.2i} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}.(1 + 2i - 1)} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}.(1 + 2i + i^2)} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}.(1+i)^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i) \\= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + i.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \mbox{ --------- 
1} \\ \mbox{Also, }
\sqrt{-i} = \sqrt{-1.i} = \sqrt{-1}.\sqrt{i} = i\sqrt{i} = i(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + i.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) \mbox{ --------from 1} \\ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + i.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \mbox{ --------- 2} \\
\mbox{Adding 1 and 2, we get} \\ \sqrt{i} + \sqrt{-i} \\ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + i.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + i.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\= i.\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} \\= i.\frac{\sqrt{2}.\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}} \\= i\sqrt{2}
$$
This is a complex number, not a real number.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there another way to prove this ?

Comment: What do you mean by $\sqrt i$? Don't forget: every complex number other than zero has **two** "square roots".

Comment: The error in your reasoning the step $\sqrt{-1 \cdot i} = (\sqrt{-1})(\sqrt{i})$. In general, with complex numbers you cannot assume $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$.

Comment: You don't need to write $\displaystyle \frac 1 2. 2i.$ You can write $\displaystyle \frac 1 2 \cdot 2i. \qquad$

Comment: The number $-i$ (like all complex numbers except $0$) has two square roots. Use the other one. Then it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so to sum up. the question is incorrect. there are 4 solutions for this because root of any number has 2 solutions. in this question  there are 2 real solutions and 2 solutions are on the imaginary axis

Answer (score 3):

Using the the polar representation for complex numbers, there holds that 
$$ \sqrt{i}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}~~~\mbox{and}~~~\sqrt{-i}=e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}$$
so that
$$ \sqrt{i}+\sqrt{-i}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}+e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: Square root is a multivaluated function on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: In my solution $e^{\pm i\frac{\pi}{4}}$ are two of the zeros of the polynomial $z^4+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $i=e^{(\pi/2) i}$ and $-i=e^{(-\pi/2) i}$

Thus $\sqrt i =  e^{(\pi/4) i}$ and $\sqrt -i =  e^{(-\pi/4) i}$

Adding the two we get $$\sqrt i+\sqrt -i =e^{(\pi/4) i}+e^{(-\pi/4) i}=2 \cos (\pi/4)=\sqrt 2$$ Which is real.